# How to make one code for 20 text boxes from 22 text boxes in total instead of 20 times the same

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I have a group of 22 text boxes. The first 20 are numbers between 1 and 10 and textbox21 an textbox22 is the total of each group of 10. I have for textbox1 until textbox20 the same code, but how can I make this easier ?

Below you see the code I have for one of these textboxes.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    korps(1) = 0
    korps1
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
                            TextBox1.SetFocus
                            Exit Sub
    End If
            If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
                TextBox1.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If
    If TextBox1.Value = 0 Then TextBox1.Value = 10
    korps(1) = TextBox1.Value
    korps1
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess my first thought would be: do you need to have that many separate text boxes? What are the differences between the text boxes? Could you just have one text box and then have it behave or display differently based on some code that runs when it appears?

Comment: Assuming ActiveX/MSForms controls, you'll need one handler per textbox, no way around it, that's how events work. But you can extract the logic into its own `OnTextBoxChanged` procedure such as the handler for `TextBox1_Change` only contains `OnTextBoxChanged TextBox1`.

Comment: Also you might have a look at the built-in [inputbox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel) which might simplify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @garbb `InputBox` is quite shitty UX, it was made for debugging purposes, not for UI design. I'll take a form with 20 textboxes any day over 20 successive inputboxes.

Comment: I would build a kind of control array as described here http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Updated link : http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the link in my comment you could create a class with the name txtBox and the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mTextBox As MSForms.Textbox

Property Set Box(nBox As MSForms.Textbox)
    Set mTextBox = nBox
End Property

Private Sub mTextBox_Change()

    If mTextBox.Value = "" Then
        mTextBox.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(mTextBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
        mTextBox.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If mTextBox.Value = 0 Then mTextBox.Value = 10

End Sub
```

In the form you would need a code similar to the following code

```
Option Explicit

Dim colTxtBoxes As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim m_txtBox As txtBox
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    Set colTxtBoxes = New Collection

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls

        If ctl.Name = "TextBox21" Or ctl.Name = "TextBox22" Then
        Else
            If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
                Set m_txtBox = New txtBox
                Set m_txtBox.Box = ctl
                colTxtBoxes.Add m_txtBox
            End If
        End If

    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which requires the code only once. Below are the procedures you will need. They should be in the code sheet of the Userform on which you have all the textboxes.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim Korps() As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' 01 Jan 2018
    ' presuming that all Tbxs are 0 upon initialisation.
    ' if they are not, transfer their initial values to Korps here.

    ReDim Korps(1 To 10, 1 To 2)
    SetTotals
End Sub

Private Function KeyPress(Tbx As MSForms.TextBox, _
                          ByVal Key As Integer) As Integer
    ' 01 Jan 2018
    ' Message is shown after each 3rd wrong entry,
    ' regardless of the Tbx in which it occurred.

    Static Count As Integer

    If Not IsNumeric(Chr(Key)) Then
        Key = 0
        Count = Count + 1
        If Count = 3 Then
            MsgBox "Only numbers may be entered", _
                    vbInformation, "Entry restrictions"
            Count = 0
        End If
    End If
    KeyPress = Key
End Function

Private Sub TbxUpdate(Tbx As MSForms.TextBox)
    ' 01 Jan 2018

    Dim Idx As Integer                      ' Tbx number
    Dim Grp As Integer                      ' 1 = 1 to 10, 2 = 11 to 20

    With Tbx
        Idx = Mid(.Name, Len("TextBox") + 1)
        Grp = Int((Idx - 1) / 10) + 1
        If Trim(.Text) = "" Then
            ' reject blank: restore previous value
            .Value = Korps(Idx, Grp)
            .SetFocus
        Else
            If .Value = 0 Then .Value = 10
            Korps(Idx, Grp) = .Value
            SetTotals Grp
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SetTotals(Optional ByVal Grp As Integer)
    ' 01 Jan 2018
    ' if Grp isn't supplied, both groups are summed up

    Dim Ttl As Double
    Dim LoopStart As Integer, LoopEnd As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    If Grp Then
        LoopStart = Grp
        LoopEnd = Grp
    Else
        LoopStart = 1
        LoopEnd = 2
    End If

    For Grp = LoopStart To LoopEnd
        Ttl = 0
        For i = 1 To 10
            Ttl = Ttl + Korps(i, Grp)
        Next i
        Me.Controls("TextBox2" & Grp).Value = Ttl
    Next Grp
End Sub
```

As you see, I took a guess at what your variable `korps` and the procedure `korps1` do.

For each of your 20 textboxes you will need the following event procedures. They are all the same except for the TextBox number in their declarations. Herein lies the superiority of Storax' suggestion to create a class instead. If you are comfortable with creating a class that is what I should recommend.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 01 Jan 2018
    TbxUpdate ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    ' 01 Jan 2018
    KeyAscii = KeyPress(ActiveControl, KeyAscii)
End Sub
```

Observe that I suggest to use events which are different from the ones you had thought of. I think you should reconsider even if you opt to create a class. The `Change` event will fire on every character entered. That is useful for the purpose of catching non-numeric entries, except that the `KeyPress` event is even more suitable for that because it can stop the character appearing in the textbox.

As for maintaining a running total, the `Change` event is adventurous because it creates senseless totals when multi-digit numbers are entered. I recommend the `Update` event instead which occurs when the user moves his focus (and the cursor) to another control.

Comment: Thank you Variatus, you have given me a very good alternative.